# Can I use a font available in Microsoft packages for my company logo?

Tags: logo

Can I use a font available in Microsoft packages for my company logo?

Do I need to additionally pay for it or is it just free to use?

Answer (score 1):

The specific answer: **read the license** that came with the font.

General answer: **Yes, you can**. Nearly all licensed typefaces allow for you to use them in any artwork you want to create--including logos. As you own a license to the type that comes with MicroSoft software--assuming you paid for the software, then yes, you can use it.

There are some exceptions, however. For example, House Industries requires you to purchase a separate license for logo use if your company takes in more than 5 million in gross revenue a year: http://www.houseind.com/fonts/licensing/pricing

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use a font available in Microsoft packages for my company logo?

I would probably say you can't but I dont know what the licence says for the font.  Check the manufacturer's website.

> Do I need to additionally pay for it or is it just free to use?

Depends on what the licence says.   You may find your answer if you visit [Microsoft typography](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/).